# Backticks having different output from $()

Tags: bash, backquote

The following code:

```sh
url="http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Durldecode%2Bbash"

line=`echo -e ${url//%/\\x}`; 
echo $line;

line=$(echo -e ${url//%/\\x}); 
echo $line;
```

Produces:

```
httpx3Ax2Fx2Fstackoverflow.comx2Fsearchx3Fqx3Durldecodex2Bbash
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=urldecode+bash
```

Shouldn't the `` and the $() produce the same result?

Comment: Backslashes' behavior is different (they're treated identically to an unquoted context only in `$(...)`). That *should* be described behind the link... and looking through, it *is*.

Comment: I linked a different duplicate that  -- while its title didn't make this clear pre-editing -- is explicitly asking about differing output from commands using the two different styles of command substitution.